# How to change the Record when scroll the mouse wheel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouseevent

I have a asp.net web application in that i have display the student records in text Boxes using ado.net Entity frame Work when i want see the record need click the next button.But i want mouse scroll event means when i scroll mouse up/down then display the next record/previous record in text boxes.Is it possible? please help me how to resolve this ..

Answer (score 0):

In C# it can be done like this:

```
textBox.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(textBox_MouseWheel);

        void resultBox_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
                ;// next student.
            else ; // prev student.
        }
```

If you can add a callback to the MouseWheel event, it works the same for asp.net.

Comment: whhhhhhat?!?! Are you eventually suggesting a postback for every little small movement of the mousewheel !?! Even if the .NET framework is the same, in ASP.NET and in web development things are different than in Windows Forms, you can't think in the same way...

Comment: ok I'm not used to web development anymore, but if you can put it in an AJAX frame, it should be doable, also I din't hear a better solution from you?

Answer (score 0):

On the mouse wheel side of things; you could bind to a "mouse wheel" event in javascript:

Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMMouseScroll

IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There are some jQuery plugins that could help normalise the differene mouse wheel implementations acorss browsers: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/mousewheel

Depending on the amount of data, you could either preload the data in the background and then "on mouse wheel move" change your recordsets. Or if you have lots of data, load the data on an ajax call.

Regarding loading the data into the recordset it's entirely possible. However I think you need to break your problem down further, as your question covers a few areas. Perhaps approaching in 2 parts:

1. Attaching to mouse wheel events
2. Changing your record sets in the client side (possibly doing an ajax call back in an update panel would be reasonably simple approach, but perhaps not that performant).